# Ember Rest Adapter - How to Call two rest services on single route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am New Ember.js and Ember-Data. With some sample tutorials I was able to understand a few basic things and started to right my own application. Now I am facing a problem, where I'm supposed to call two different REST services: one to display the table value in hbs and another to load data to a drop down select box in my Route, but I couldn't achieve this.

I tried most of the approaches given in blogs, but I can't find a solution. Can you please guide me on this?

**Approach**

```
model : function() {
    return this.store.find('User');
},
customers: function(){
  return this.store.find('Customer');
},
```

**Error I Got**

```
Error while processing route: AdminUser Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing appears to be an issue with your API response. It's saying that it's returning a single user object as opposed to an array of users.

Once you've got that resolved, you can use `Ember.RSVP.hash` to return a collection of promises that must all be resolved for the model to be considered resolved. Then use setupController to set the users as the model, and customers as a separate property on the controller.

```
model : function() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    users: this.store.find('User'),
    customers: this.store.find('Customer')
  });
},

setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model.users);
  controller.set('customers', model.customers);
}
```